# Manipulate / Change site title with tx_metaseo

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I'm not able to change the title of the browser. That's how I render the title:

```
page.headerData.5 = TEXT
page.headerData.5.field = subtitle // title
page.headerData.5.wrap = <title>|&nbsp;&#124; IrgendEinName</title>
```

... which works. In addition I use tx_metaseo, which also works. If I now want to manually change a site title in Properties->SEO and then under ...

title-TAG (absolute, without prefix/suffix)

... I can't change the title.

My solution now:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 24]
page.headerData.5 = TEXT
page.headerData.5.field = tx_metaseo_pagetitle
page.headerData.5.wrap = <title>|&nbsp;&#124; IrgendEinName</title>
[end]

[globalVar = TSFE:id != 24]
page.headerData.5 = TEXT
page.headerData.5.field = subtitle // title
page.headerData.5.wrap = <title>|&nbsp;&#124; IrgendEinName</title>
[end]
```

Obviously for one site it's fine. But are there any other options? E.g. with .if.isNull. or .if.isFalse. where I say 'IF tx_metaseo_pagetitle IS EMPTY SELECT title ? 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/Functions/If/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if.notEmpty should work but I can't test it now. Quickly I found this solution:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:page|tx_metaseo_pagetitle=]
[else]
  page.headerData.5 >
  page.headerData.5 = TEXT
  page.headerData.5 {
      wrap = <title>|</title>
      field = tx_metaseo_pagetitle
  }
[global]
```